# redirect to actionResult method from an api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

```
[HttpPost]
    public void insertData(string productid)
    {
        //insert to db
        string uri = this.Url.Link("Default", new { controller = "AddProducts", action = "Index" });
        //Response.Redirect(Url.Action("", ""));
    }
```

after inserting to the database i want to redirect to an actionResult method.i have a void method, what do i return it as?

Comment: What do you mean? If you want to return a result to the browser, just return an ActionResult from your own method and make sure you put enough data in there to render your view. If you want to redirect to another URL, return a 302 with the new URL

Comment: i meant in inside the api controller.actionResult only works inside mvc controller

Answer (score 0):

Is this an MVC controller or a web Api controller?

**If MVC :**

You must return an ActionResult instead of void.

Your code will look like this one.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddProduct(string productid)
    {
        //Add product to db logic goes here

        return RedirectToAction("{Your parameters here}");
    }
```

It's your task to go deeper into details. Take a look at this one to know more about ActionResult - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionresult%28v=vs.118%29.aspx

**If it's a web api:**

You only return Http response messages. http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/action-results

Comment: Redirection means that the response is a 302 status with the new URL. `RedirectToAction` simply creates the appropriate URL. In Web API, just call one of the [Redirect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller.redirect.aspx) or [RedirectToRoute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller.redirecttoroute.aspx) methods